# Regex split preserving strings and escape character

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

I need to split a string on C#, based on space as delimiter and preserving the quotes.. this part is ok.
But additionally, I want to allow escape character for string `\"` to allow include other quotes inside the quotes.

Example of what I need:

```
One Two "Three Four" "Five \"Six\""
```

To:

- One
- Two
- Three Four
- Five "Six"

This is the regex I am currently using, it is working for all the cases except `"Five \"Six\""`

```
//Split on spaces unless in quotes
        List<string> matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[\""].+?[\""]|[^ ]+")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Value.Trim('"'))
            .ToList();
```

I'm looking for any Regex, that would do the trick.

Comment: Does this _need_ to be a regex pattern? Typically when it comes to nested logic another tool is better suited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var input = "One Two \"Three Four\" \"Five \\\"Six\\\"\"";
// Console.WriteLine(input); // => One Two "Three Four" "Five \"Six\""
List<string> matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?s)""(?<r>[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*)""|(?<r>\S+)")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x.Groups["r"].Value, @"\\(.)", "$1"))
            .ToList();
foreach (var s in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/oF07UK).

The result is

```
One
Two
Three Four
Five "Six"
```

The `(?s)"(?<r>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|(?<r>\S+)` regex matches

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` equivalent to make `.` match newlines, too
- `"(?<r>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` - `"`, then Group "r" capturing any zero or more chars other than `"` and `\` and then zero or more sequences of any escaped char and zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`, and then a `"` is matched
- `|` - or
- `(?<r>\S+)` - Group "r": one or more whitespaces.

The `.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x.Groups["r"].Value, @"\\(.)", "$1"))` takes the Group "r" value and unescapes (deletes a `\` before) all escaped chars.

Comment: This is working, however if one of the strings is for example a path "C:\\Folder0\\Folder1\\file.txt", the regex removes all the backslashes and the string gets converted to something like this "C:Folder0Folder1file.txt"

Comment: @LordCaos Sure, because in that case, all backslashes must be doubled in the input text, since ``\`` is an escaping symbol. In string literals, backslashes are used as escape operators, so you need to account for that in the source string.

Comment: They are already doubled, it only works if I quadruple them: "C:\\\\Folder0\\\\Folder1\\\\file.txt", can this be fixed from the regex?

Comment: @LordCaos You are not  using verbatim string literals, so 4 ``\``s are actually double backslashes. Yes, that is correct. This will work now with the regex I suggest. BTW, regex does not fix the strings, the strings must be properly escaped. Else, there is no regularity and regex won't work here.